# How to monitor in which dom user click in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-event-emitter

I want to monitor the click of user in angular application, rather dont want to mannual configure for each click event, I want some thing at higher level that tells me each time where user clicked in application.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('click, callback)` is all you need

Comment: Keep in mind angular is just fancy JavaScript. Anything you can do in JS is also available to you.

Comment: @Lends how do i know where user click, on which DOM

Comment: @HiteshGarg you have arguments in your callback function. The first one is the `event`. You can get a lot of info from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@HostListener('click') onClick()
```

might be just what you are looking for...

You can add it to your component and it will be called on each click event